# Communication between two .net core containers

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

net core application. I have webapp and api application.
Below is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  enrichment.webapi:
    container_name: enrichment.webapi
    ports:
            - 8000:80
            - 8001:443
    environment:
            - "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+"
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypassword
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d/https/:/https/
    build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Enrichment.WebApi/Dockerfile
  enrichment.webapp:
   image: enrichment.web
   ports:
            - 7000:80
            - 7001:443
   environment:
            - "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+"
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypassword
   volumes:
      - ./conf.d/https/:/https/
   build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Enrichment.Web/Dockerfile
   depends_on:
            - enrichment.webapi
```

When I do docker-compose up I see below when I do docker ps

> 0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32835->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32834->443/tcp

for the api app. When I do https://localhost:32834/index.html it works fine. But this port 32834 dynamically assigned. I want to set some static port so that I can handle my CORS in my web app. Each time this port is keep on getting changed when I rebuild docker-compose file. So Is there any way to handle this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The expose tag will let you expose ports without publishing them to the host machine, but they will be exposed to the containers networks.

Comment: Thanks Ashok. 0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32835->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32834->443/tcp in this 80 and 443 container ports right? I dint set anything 32834. I am not able to understand this port mapping here

Comment: for my web app it is staright forward 0.0.0.0:7000->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7001->443/tcp   but api app how this came not able to understand

Comment: It looks like the ports for the `enrichment.webapi` are correctly assigned (8000 -> 80 and 8001 -> 443), but Docker substitutes ports 7000 and 7001 on the other container with dynamic ones. Are your local ports 7000/7001 perhaps already in use?
Also, including the Dockerfile in question (`Enrichment.WebApi/Dockerfile`) would help.